# Could Not Connect my react app via ip4 address

Tags: reactjs, connection, localhost, ip, web-deployment

This is my first time making react project.

After I run my project with npm run start, I can connect to it via localhost:3000 and 127.0.0.1:3000 without any problem.

But when I try to connect it with my LAN address on the same computer it shows

**Could Not Connect**
Description: Could not connect to the requested server host.

It also shown an error on browser console.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (internal error - server connection terminated)

This same project can be open via ip4 if I run it on my laptop. I can even open it from my mobile in the same wifi.

My computer is own by company so I think something might block it.

Please give me your suggestions on how to fix this problem. What could possibly cause this problem.

Any insight would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: If the IP address starts with 192.168, then it can only be accessed by devices in the same network. If it's not, you can't just enter the IP and access it.

Comment: So that is why. Mine is 172.26. Is there anyway to make it work?

Comment: you'll have to play with your router settings. if you don't do it properly, you'll exposing your devices for attacks from the whole internet. google is your friend here. it might just be easier to deploy it somewhere like github pages, netlify, heroku.

Comment: I see! Thank you for explaining. Really help me alot. I just want test it between 2 devices buy I guess I will do that after we deploy it on our server

Answer (score -1):

Run `HOST=0.0.0.0 npm run start`

Check your IP. `<your-ip>:3000` would work.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/ for setting HOST environment variables.

Comment: doesn't work. maybe because of my IP like other person said ? 

Thank you anyway

Comment: two machines must be on the same LAN